# Dropwizard metrics (Meter) 3.1.0 + InfluxDB 0.9.x + Grafana stuck at the latest value

Tags: dropwizard, influxdb, grafana, codahale-metrics

As the title suggests, I am using the above stack for insight into the frequency of a particular method call over time.

This is how collecting metrics is set up in the code:

```
 public void searchProducts(Query query) {
    Meter meter = metricRegistry.meter(MetricRegistry.name("search.products"));
    meter.mark();

    // perform search
    // ...
  }
```

This is how the graph is configured in Grafana:

[image: graph configuration in Grafana]

And this is how the resulting graph looks like:

[image: resulting graph]

As you can see, when there are no method calls, the line is stuck at the latest value. There are several drops to 0 (right after two big 'humps' at the beginning and one more at the end) which happened when I stopped the application.

Shouldn't the line drop to 0 after some time passes after the last mark? E.g. the application is started, several method calls occur, 1 second passes between each method call and then after about 30 seconds, the line should go back down to 0 and stay there. Like this:

- **00:00** start of the application (line is at **0**)
- **00:01** method call (line goes to **1**)
- **00:02** method call (line goes to **2**)
- **00:03** method call (line goes to **3**)
- **00:04** *nothing happens* (line stays at **3**)
- **00:05** *nothing happens* (line stays at **3**)
- ...
- **00:30** *nothing happens* (line drops to **0**)

Instead, [Meter](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/manual/core/#meters) in this case seems to behave just like the [Counter](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/manual/core/#counters) - incrementing values for the whole lifecycle of the application.

**EDIT:** Here is how the graph looks like even with *Display styles -> null point mode -> null as zero* is set. Graph looks exactly the same with *Display styles -> null point mode -> null* setting, as well.

[image]

**UPDATE**: Sorry for the delay in response - only recently I came back to this problem. I found out the root cause of the problem - it was that underlying database was InfluxDB with custom Metrics Reporters (there are no official ones for InfluxDB) and there was a bug in the reporter logic.

Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: IMO the `Meter` is doing a different thing than you are expecting from it:
> The mean rate is the average rate of events. It’s generally useful for trivia, but as it represents
> the total rate for your application’s entire lifetime (e.g., the total number of requests handled,
> divided by the number of seconds the process has been running), it doesn’t offer a sense of recency.
> Luckily, meters also record three different exponentially-weighted moving average rates:
> the 1-, 5-, and 15-minute moving averages.

Comment: Take a look at the test case: https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/blob/3.2-development/metrics-core/src/test/java/com/codahale/metrics/MeterTest.java (Two comments because one is too long)

Comment: Looking at the test cases, this does look like what I am looking for. What metric would you otherwise suggest? I have tried with the Counter, but it doesn't do what I need - every time a Counter.inc() is called it increments the value, but never descends (unless Counter.dec() is called)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For graphs, there is an option under the Display Styles tab where you can choose how to handle null values. If *connected* is chosen, then you will see the behavior you describe. There are two other options, *null* -> no line or *null as zero* -> line drops to zero.

On older versions of Grafana, the option is call Null point mode ([docs here](http://docs.grafana.org/reference/graph/#display-styles))

Here is a screenshot of the option in Grafana 3.1:

[image: Null value drop down]

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel for the response. I did what you suggested but nothing seems to have changed. Please see the edited question for more details.

Comment: If you change the Chart Options to Points instead of Lines and the Null point mode to null, do you see points for the interval where you expect it to be zero? If there are points with values not equal to zero, then it would seem that the problem is with Meter and not Grafana.

Comment: Changing lines to points and null point mode to null gives the same results (null values are still present). This might indeed be a problem with a meter setup. Will write back when I find out

Comment: Sorry for the late response, only recently I came back to solving this problem. This is indeed the correct answer. I found out the root cause of my problem - it was that underlying database was InfluxDB with custom Metrics Reporters (there are no official ones for InfluxDB) and there was a bug in the reporter logic.

Comment: @DaniloRadenovic great that you fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

That type of output may be from using the default  ExponentiallyDecayingReservoir.  This will result in the most recent value being returned when there have been no recent updates. 
The reservoir never gets flushed clean.

Potential solutions include:

- switch to a sliding time window reservoir (least performant, easiest to implement)
- flush the values each time you report/record the data

A more in depth post can be found here (http://taint.org/2014/01/16/145944a.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use either a meter or counter to sum up or calculate count(total) per arbitrary interval:

```
hitcount(perSecond(your.count), '1day')
```

Afaik it does all the black magic inside. Including but not limited to `summarize(scaleToSeconds(nonNegativeDerivative(your.count),1), '1day')`
and also there should be scaling according to carbon's retention periods (one or many) that fall into chosen aggregation interval.